# Changing letters by ascii value

Tags: c++

I am trying to use ascii values to check different values of a letter to decipher a simple Cesar cipher.  I am running into problems when the program tries to check a letter after z.  I am using all lower case so if the letter is on z it should move to the beginning of the alphabet again.  My code is as follows

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    string unencr;
    char temp;
    cout << "Enter string:" << endl << endl;
    cin >> unencr;
    for(int i = 0; i<26; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < unencr.size(); j++){
            temp = unencr[j];
            if ((int)temp + i <= 122){
                temp = (int)temp + i;
            }
            if ((int)temp + i > 122){
                temp = (((int)temp +i) % 122)+96;
            }
            cout << temp;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are the problems you are running into?

Comment: I am having a problem with my second if statement it isn't working correctly.  If i put in g as the input the out put is ghijklmnopacegikmoqsabcdef instead of ghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

Comment: You're potentially adding `i` to `temp` twice. Say `temp` is 112 (p) and `i` is 8. Then in the first if statement, you will add 8 to temp because 112+8 = 120 <= 122. In the second if statement, since 120+8 > 122, you add `i` to `temp` again.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in your `if` statement you say `(((int)temp +i) % 122)+96;` But what if the char was 155 this would then make it equal to 130. Which is out of the bounds of a-z.

What you want to do instead: `if(temp > 122)` then you should `(temp-122)%122 + 97` instead of moding it by itself.

Comment: And replace the ordinal values by character literals: `97 == 'a'`, `122 == 'z'`.

Comment: @Kay I find that to be style. I see nothing wrong with casting and knowing the ascii value to compare too.

Comment: So, you know the ASCII table out of your head? What is `'$'` then? It is really bad style to use the ASCII value in here. How can one tell if 96 or 97 is correct at first glance? But every reader can tell 'a' and 'b' apart.

Comment: It's a matter of good style versus bad style. Using character literals is objectively better in every way that matters.

Comment: @Jay I tried using your logic and I am still not getting the correct output.

Comment: @Kay the point here is that its not wheather its bad coding or good. It's still correct, so that's not gunna help him. We can advise him to change that but its up to him. Anyway Brad that's because I don't really know what you are doing with that logic. A Caesar cipher is just some number of rotations. So depending on that number you just wanna add to each char that offset. (String[I]+offset)%'z' + 'a'

Comment: Every bit of advice helps. As I said before, it is difficult to spot the error if someone mistyped `96` instead of `97`, but you will notice a `'b'` instead of an `'a'`. (Offtopic: I *love* the design of your website!)

Answer (score 0):

To change a single character `c`, use this line:

```
 c = ((c - 'a' + 13) % 26) + 'a';

       c - 'a'                   // convert to position in the alphabet, 0 based
       c - 'a' + 13              // rot13 (or any other shift that you want)
      (c - 'a' + 13) % 26        // wrap around after 'z'
     ((c - 'a' + 13) % 26) + 'a' // convert it to ASCII again
```

Also you might want to embrace all of C++'s features:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    // read a whole line instead of a single word:
    std::string str;
    std::getline(std::cin, str);

    // iterate over the string, not over the letters of the alphabet:
    for (char &c : str) {
        if (('a' <= c) && (c <= 'z')) {
            c = (((c + 13) - 'a') % 26) + 'a';
        }
    }

    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok I changed my code so my statement is if (temp + i > 'z'){
    temp = ((temp - 'a' + i) % 26) + 'a';
    }

Comment: I am still getting an odd output. It is correct for the first few letters then something goes wrong.

Comment: How did you come up with `if (temp + i > 'z')`? You need to test if the initial range matches: `if (('a' <= c) && (c <= 'z'))`.

Comment: @Brad: As long as you know that `temp` is always a lowercase letter, you don't need an `if` statement. The `mod` operation handles the letters wrapping around, if that happens.

Comment: @pac "are you sure?" (mind the spaces and the punctuation mark)